# How do I dynamically created nested resources with unique ids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I have a nested form using Spree's `line_item`.  I have attached a ticket object to `spree_line_item`.  When I update_attributes only the last name is captured because the dynamically generated input id's are all the same.

EDIT: By last name, I mean the last record. So, if there are 2 'first_name'/'last_name' combinations, only the 2nd combination is captured.

line_item_decorator.rb

```
Spree::LineItem.class_eval do
    has_many :tickets, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :tickets
end
```

ticket.rb

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :line_item
end
```

permitted_attributes.rb

```
permitted_attributes.rb

    module Spree
      module PermittedAttributes
        ATTRIBUTES = [
          ...
          :taxonomy_attributes,
          :ticket_attributes,
          :user_attributes,
          :variant_attributes
        ]

        mattr_reader *ATTRIBUTES

        ...

        @@line_item_attributes = [:id, :variant_id, :quantity, :ticket_attributes]

        ...


        @@ticket_attributes = [:id, :line_item_id, :first_name, :last_name, :start_date, 
        :end_date, :time]

        ...
      end
    end
```

order_decorator.rb

```
Spree::Order.class_eval do
    remove_checkout_step :registration
    insert_checkout_step :tickets, :before => :address
end
```

tickets.html.erb

```
<table>
  <%= form_for :line_item do |line_item_form| %>
    <% @order.line_items.each do |line_item| %>

      For <%= line_item.start_date %>, provide the names for your <%= line_item.quantity %> <%= line_item.name %> <%= line_item.variant.option_values.first.presentation %> tickets:
      <% (1..line_item.quantity).each do %>
        <%= line_item_form.fields_for :tickets do |ticket_fields| %>
          <tr>
            <td class="line_item_ticket">
              <%= ticket_fields.label :first_name %>
              <%= ticket_fields.text_field :first_name %>
            </td>
            <td class="line_item_ticket">
              <%= ticket_fields.label :last_name %>
              <%= ticket_fields.text_field :last_name %>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <% end -%>
      <% end -%>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Does "When I update_attributes only the last name is captured" mean that only the last 'first_name' and 'last_name' get saved? Or are you saying that only 'last_name' is saved?

Comment: Oh! good point, only the last record gets saved.  The final 'first_name' and 'last_name'.

Comment: I have not used Spree so I don't know if it automatically does this for you (if not then this may be the cause). But normally with nested attributes you have to make sure you build the nested model X times in the controller, where X is the number of them that you want to be able to save. For example: "10.times { @line_item.tickets.build }" would go in the controller#new action. You may want to check to be sure that Spree is actually building a new ticket dynamically.

Comment: I think you're right.  For some reason, I thought this was created automatically from the rails end, like the Project-Tasks Bates railscast.  But I did have to do it by hand.